# How to upgrade php version in wamp?

Tags: php, wamp

Currently I'm using php version 5.1.6 in wamp server. I'm trying to use phpexcel library to read .xls and .xlsx files. Phpexcel library  minimum  requirement is php version 5.2.0. So how can i solve this issue or how to upgrade php version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you probably need to to reinstall the wamp server with the latest version. Backup your files before doing that

Comment: is it a ready-to-use wamp stack or installed manually part by part?

Comment: ready to use wamp server only..

Answer (score 5):

Here is [all php add-on](http://www.wampserver.com/en/php-addons/). Select the one you need and download/install it.

Comment: Does this affect already existing applications running on wamp? Is this safe?Will I be able to remove this?

Comment: Yep, it's just add-on. It will add a new php version but keep the previous one and you can switch between them.

Comment: It seems wamp has removed add-on page.

Answer (score 2):

you have to upgrade your entire wamp:

backup your database.

backup your code

uninstall wamp

install new wamp

test that local host works

restore your database ( first change max_allowed_packet in mysql.ini to 10M)

enable rewrite module in apache